# Simple UIScrollview with UIImageView with zooming

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, crash

I have an application that loads images into a UITableViewController, (Wine Labels), then you can navigate to the Item Details.  On this page you can see a larger image of the Wine Label...IOS 6.1...

The app works for a short amount of time, then just CRASHES, not on ANY given line. The app just shuts down and I don't see ANY error message anywhere.  I am having difficulties finding documentation on the correct way to troubleshoot this type of shutdown.  Usually, if I crash, it fails on a line and I can usually find the problem, but in this case, Xcode is just pulling out of Debug mode(but NOT shuttind down).  I don't see ANY errors in the console...Where else can I look?  Xcode version is 4.6.

Any advice would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: did you try setting a breakpoint on throw of all exceptions?

Comment: also, are you reusing your tableview cells by calling dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier ?

Comment: In the UITableViewController, I was loading the full image into the cell.  I think it ran into memory problems, not sure.  I found some code that limited the size of the image when it loaded it into the cell.  After I applied that code, the app quit crashing...So basically, I guessed right, but I wish I would have gotten an error or something.  Yes, I did have the breakpoint set for all exceptions.  That didn't help...Yes I was reusing the tableview cells with dequeue....  Thanks for responding...